How can I use Office JS add-in to track the coordinates of a shape in PowerPoint?
When I use Office JS (JavaScript API for Office) add-in to track the coordinates of a shape in PowerPoint as it moves but I didn't get any coordinates over slides, I guess we can use the Office JavaScript API to interact with PowerPoint, but Office JS currently doesn't directly support mouse event listeners for shapes.
I'm developing a PowerPoint add-in using Office JS, and I need to track the coordinates of a shape on a slide as it moves. Specifically, I want to capture and log the position of a shape whenever it's moved or resized.
I understand that Office JS provides APIs to interact with shapes and slides, but I'm not sure how to continuously track the position of a shape in real-time or how to get updated coordinates when the shape is moved.
Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this with Office JS? For instance, how can I get the position of a shape after it has been moved or resized, and how can I set up an event or mechanism to track these changes?

I'm afraid that there is no way to track shape movements with Office.js at this time. But it is a good idea. You can suggest it at Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas.
